# Insert object into dynamic key nested array

Tags: javascript

Desired result: `Insert an object into each dynamicItem` and have the full `obj` object.

```
const obj = {
  item1: {},
  item2: {
    dynamicItem1: [{ id: 'one' }, ], // add another prop here {type: 'added'}
    dynamicItem2: [{ id: 'one' }, ] // add another prop here {type: 'added'}
  },
}
```

My attempts: I managed to insert the object, but i can't think how to rebuild the full object and it also feels like i'm doing it wrong already.

```
const result = Object.keys(obj.item2).map(key => {
    return obj.item2[key].map(item => ({ ...item, type: 'added' }))
})
```

Comment: If it's okay to mutate `obj`, then: `obj?.item2?.dynamicItem1.push({type: 'added'});`. And, similarly: `obj?.item2?.dynamicItem2.push({type: 'added'});`. Please try & share feedback.

Comment: I don't know the name of `dynamicItem1 ` key. It's why i called it dynamic.

Comment: Okay, so, we need to add `{type: 'added'}` to every `array` value within `item2` object - is that correct?

Comment: Why did you choose `.map()` when `.forEach()` would be the more obvious tool (unless you need an actual copy of `obj`)? Why `Object.keys()` when you need the values of the `obj` (-> Òbject.values()` or `Object.entries()`)?

Comment: Split up the steps and you will find answers to all of them here on SO: iterate over all (unknown) properties of an object, add property to existing object[, clone an object], ...

Comment: @jsN00b correct

Comment: Please try this and share your feedback: `const res = {...obj, item2: Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj.item2).map(([k,v]) => ([k, [...v].concat([{type: 'added'}])])))};`. Specifically what errors or issues are faced. And, as @Andreas has noted, SO has all of these ideas in various questions. :-)

Comment: @CristianMuscalu - what about this? https://jsfiddle.net/libik/hujx7fz6/4/ (cannot post it here as they closed it :/ )

Comment: _"...they closed it"_ - because all necessary steps have already been answered: how to iterate over properties of an object, how to add a new property to an object. So no need for yet another custom answer.

Comment: @libik big thanks for going out of you way to help a brother out! I will use your solution <3

Comment: @CristianMuscalu - sure thing! btw: the copying of object is not necessary if you are fine that original object will change. Also the library used there is `lodash` (the `_` sign)